# Efficient insertion technique for std::set C++

Tags: c++, insert, find, set

Which is a better(more optimized or faster technique) code:

**Find + Insert**

```
for(int i = 0; i < A.length(); i++){
    set<char> s;
    s.insert(A[i]);
    len = 1;
    for(int j = i+1; j < A.length(); j++){
        if(s.find(A[j]) == s.end()){
            s.insert(A[j]);
        }
        else{ //Duplicate char found so break
            break;
        }
        len++;
    }
    if(len > maxm) maxm = len;
    s.clear();
}
```

Or,

**Insert + UseReturnedPair**

```
for(int i = 0; i < A.length(); i++){
    set<char> s;
    pair<set<char>::iterator, bool> ret;
    s.insert(A[i]);
    len = 1;
    for(int j = i+1; j < A.length(); j++){
       ret = s.insert(A[j]);
       if(ret.second == false) break;  //using *pair* returned from set::insert
       len++;
    }
    if(len > maxm) maxm = len;
    s.clear();
}
```

In my opinion, later one looks more optimized, as it gets rid of extra overhead of `set::find`. Is my observation correct? Which one is more recommended?

Comment: in the second version you can even skip checking the result .`if(ret.second..`, if an element is there already, nothing will happen.

Comment: @dau Actually this code I wrote for solving "Given a string, 
find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters.". So there is a need to break out of loop as soon as you find a repeating character.

Comment: then you don't need an ordered structure, you can use `unordered_set` which is implemented as a hash map and it will be faster compared to `set`'s tree. Actually you can do that in one pass `O(n)` without even having a separate container. I'll let the exercise to you :)

Comment: @dau_sama yes...I worked on the above code, and found out that `vector<bool> ch(26)` is a much better data struture to use in above case. Using hashing technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second version is a tad bit faster (VS 2015, Debug x86):

```
A.length() == 564
1) 62ms
2) 56ms
```

The reason why the second version is a bit faster is because [`std::set::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert) already searches through its container to find a possible duplicate. This means that in the first version, you are searching through the set 2 times, while the second version does this 1 time.

Note that with optimization enabled, the time is reduced to less than 1ms for both versions, so basically "it doesn't matter".

Comment: Sure that benchmarking in Debug mode tells you anything?

Comment: @SpamBot No, it doesn't. Just added it to highlight the difference